# RSA - Encryption with negative exponent

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, rsa, pkcs#11

Well guys I am trying to encrypt (actually sign) data using Public and Private exponent and modulus, It is in C#.NET and I can't use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` because it needs also both prime numbers and other CRT stuff.

So I am trying to do following:

```
private Byte[] signData()
{
  BigInteger biPrivEx = new BigInteger(this.privEx); // Those are byte[]
  BigInteger biPubEx = new BigInteger(this.pubEx);
  BigInteger biMod = new BigInteger(this.mod);          

  BigInteger cyph = BigInteger.ModPow(new BigInteger(pkcs11), biPrivEx, biMod); // This raise exception

  return cyph.ToByteArray();;
}
```

But the problem is I am getting `Out Of Range Exception` because my private exponent is negative number.

What am I doing wrong? Or is possible to easily recovery CRT from this? Or maybe is there any better way how to do it?
In different program I am able to this with data I am using, so I have got reference to verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you got a negative private exponent in the first place. Depending on how you got this broken exponent try:

1. Adding `n` to it
2. Concating a `00` byte to the array, to make it parse correctly.

You should also be careful about endianness issues. .net's `BigInteger` uses little endian, other binary formats might use big endian.

---

Try:

```
BigInteger ParseBinaryLE(byte[] raw)
{
   return new BigInteger(raw.Concat(new byte[]{0}).ToArray());
}

BigInteger ParseBinaryBE(byte[] raw)
{
   return new BigInteger(raw.Reverse().Concat(new byte[]{0}).ToArray());
}
```

---

AFAIK it is also possible to recover `P` and `Q` (and from those the rest of the parameters) when you know `e`, `d` and `n`.

Comment: My input looks like `Byte[] PrivateEx = StringToByteArray("FFAABBCC`)` (just example) and I do not think it is negative, there is no minus sing anywhere. May this be caused by BigInteger?

Comment: @Johny BigInteger assumes the last bit is a sign bit. So you need to append `00`. You might also need to reverse the array first. I've added two candidate functions.

Comment: Okay, no it finally calculate, but result is still wrong, anyway why it might be necessary to reverse array?

Comment: @Johny if the binary key was big-endian, you need to reverse it, so `BigInteger` which assumed little-endian reads it correctly.